# Setting overflow scroll using javascript

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

I have a page where overflow-x is forced hidden(using !important) due to the usage of a css file(UIFix.css). But I need to have scrollbar visible. I can't modify the UIFix.css file.So I added the following at the end of the page below the UIFix.css file and it works.

```
<style>
body{overflow-x: scroll !important;}
</style>
```

However I want to make this fix using javascript instead of keeping the tags at the end of the page. I am trying the below piece of code on document load, but it does not work.

```
$('body').css('overflow-x','scroll','important');
```

I tried the above from chrome console and it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using `cssText`.

```
$('body').css('cssText', 'overflow-x: scroll !important;');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a css class that has your desired css such as:

```
.overflow-x-scroll {
    overflow-x: scroll !important;
}
```

Then add the class to the element with `addClass()`:

```
$("body").addClass("overflow-x-scroll");
```